# OpsHub Unable to set Source EndPoint to TFS2015 with error TF31002

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-2015, opshub

I am trying to use OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility (Free Version) to migrate the Work Items in TFS2015 (Version 14.102.25423.0) to VSTS.
When I set the TFS server URL as Source EndPoint, I got the TF31002 error as shown in the following screenshot:
[TF31002 Error when setting the Source EndPoint to a TFS2015 Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW6bp.png)

I am able to connect to the TFS Server via all of my browsers and Visual Studio (2015/2017).

I tried some solutions like:
 - clearing IE cache/cookies
 - clearing TFS cache
 - delete Visual Studio TokenManager folder on registy

Thanks in advance for any provided solution.

My machine is behind a proxy et here are the configuration in settings.properties:

```
action=update
installationLocation=C:\\Program Files\\OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility
httpHostName=my_proxy_ip_address
httpPort=8080
httpUsername=my_company_username
httpPassword=my_password
httpNonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1

useSameParametersForHTTPS=true

httpsHostName=
httpsPort=
httpsUsername=
httpsPassword=
httpsNonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Is the machine behind a proxy? Quite possibly the browsers and VS are enabled to use auto-settings for the said proxy.

Comment: Yes, it's behind a proxy. I added the environment variable _JAVA_OPTIONS and also used the ProxyUtility coming with OpsHub.

Comment: 404 Error most likely points to the tools inability to yet connect to the TFS end point. Which in turn means the proxy settings either are not taking effect or incorrectly configured.Can you post additional information of the proxy (without revealing private info, of course) so that the correctness/syntax can be validated.

Comment: Here are the configuration in settings.properties : action=update
installationLocation=C:\\Program Files\\OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility
httpHostName=proxy_ip_address
httpPort=8080
httpUsername=my_username
httpPassword=my_password
httpNonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
#Use pipe operator for separating non-proxy hosts
useSameParametersForHTTPS=true

httpsHostName=
httpsPort=
httpsUsername=
httpsPassword=
httpsNonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1

Comment: Then I run the command:  java –jar <path-to-jar>/ProxyUtility.jar from the proper folder ==> C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility\OpsHub_Resources\jre\bin

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you'll have to enable two of the OVSMU's processes to utilize the proxy configuration as done in the _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable.

1. C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility\Other_Resources\Resources\TFSUtility\ovsmu.exe.config
2. C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility\Other_Resources\Resources\TFSUtility\TFSService\opshubtfsservice.exe.config

Open each of the above mentioned configuration file in a text editor (as an Admin) and un-comment the following XML node structure.

```
<!-- <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="false">
      <module type="com.opshub.tfs.test.Proxy, opshubtfsservice" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net> -->
```

Remove the comments and restart the tool, you should be able to connect to the end points then.

Comment: These settings were already uncommented. Still unable to connect to the end points.

Comment: Hmm, this seems strange. Do you have an authentication based proxy or password less proxy configuration?

Comment: We have an authentication based proxy.